# Batch file string manipulation

Tags: string, batch-file, build-process, environment-variables

This is a very specific question, however;

Say I have a batch file running from\located in the directory `c:\data\src\branch_1`

How do I set my environment variable `%buildpath%` to `c:\build\bin\branch_1` in a batch file?

(To be extra clear, if the same batch file is located in `c:\foo\bar\branch_2` I want it to set `%buildpath%` to `c:\build\bin\branch_2`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use the environment variable `%~dp0` to get you the drive and path of the batch file currently running. From there, it's a not-very-efficient method of stripping off the end of that string character by character and building a new string.

For example, the batch file:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set olddir=%~dp0
echo Current directory is: !olddir!
if "!olddir:~-1!" == "\" (
    set olddir=!olddir:~0,-1!
)
set lastbit=
:loop
if not "!olddir:~-1!" == "\" (
    set lastbit=!olddir:~-1!!lastbit!
    set olddir=!olddir:~0,-1!
    goto :loop
)
set newdir=c:\build\bin\!lastbit!
echo New directory is: !newdir!
endlocal
```

running as `c:\data\src\branch1\qq.cmd` returns the following:

```
Current directory is: C:\data\src\branch1\
New directory is: c:\build\bin\branch1
```

As to how it works, you can use `!xyz:~n,m!` for doing a substring of an environment variable, and negative `m` or `n` means from the end rather than the beginning. So the first `if` block strips off the trailing `\` if it's there.

The loop is similar but it transfers characters from the end of the path to a new variable, up until the point where you find the `\`. So then you have the last bit of the path, and it's a simple matter to append that to your fixed new path.

Comment: Nice, was just looking at this and using for on %0 with %~di%~pi :P

Comment: Thanks, but, that was the easy part. The hard part is to find the last \ and substring from there :/

Comment: Sorry, @Viktor, I should have read the question a little more closely. Updated my answer to meet the _actual_ specs rather than what I thought they were :-)

Answer (score 1):

Old case, but still...

easy way of setting current directory into variable.

```
@echo off
cd > dir.tmp
set /p directory= <dir.tmp
echo %directory%    <-- do whatever you want to the variable. I just did a echo..
del dir.tmp > nul
```

Comment: If you only need the current directory, you can
    set directory=%CD%
However, @ViktorSehr asked for the directory that the batch file exists in as a file.